# simple Echo Error

Tags: php, syntax, echo

i try to make a while{ part in php, to read out a mysql db. Works perfectly, only with the output i have problems:

```
echo "<div id=\"content\"><ul class=\"pageitem\"><li class=\"store\"><a href=\"index.html\"><span class=\"image\" style=\"background-image: url('<?php echo \". $zeile['image'] . \"; ?>')\"></span><span class=\"name\"><?php echo \". $zeile['title'] . \"; ?></span><span class=\"arrow\"></span></a></li></ul>";
```

Error is:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in D:\xampplite\htdocs\harti\products.php on line 40

Sry i'm really new with php, i think this is a simple mistake but cannot find it.

thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `<?php` again...

```
echo "<div id=\"content\"><ul class=\"pageitem\"><li class=\"store\"><a href=\"index.html\"><span class=\"image\" style=\"background-image: url('". $zeile['image'] . "')\"></span><span class=\"name\">". $zeile['title'] . "</span><span class=\"arrow\"></span></a></li></ul></div>";
```

Also, you forgot to close the DIV.

Instead, you could do something like this (outside `<?php` and `?>`):

```
<div id="content">
  <ul class="pageitem">
    <li class="store">
      <a href="index.html">
        <span class="image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $zeile['image']; ?>')"></span>
        <span class="name"><?php echo $zeile['title']; ?></span>
        <span class="arrow"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @matthias: If you're using echo, you are already in "PHP mode" so you don't need to enter it again to "make it"

Comment: so i have the same Problem: echo "<div id=\"content\"><ul class=\"pageitem\"><li class=\"store\"><a href=\"index.html\"><span class=\"image\" style=\"background-image: url('. $zeile['image'] .')\"></span><span class=\"name\">$zeile['title']</span><span class=\"arrow\"></span></a></li></ul>";

Comment: That large HTML template style is by far the best way to output HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on how strings work in PHP:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

If you use double quotes you can do this:

```
echo "<b>{$myarray[$index]}</b>";
```

Or you can do this:

```
echo '<a href="'.$src.'">blah</a>';
```

Note how I used single quotes to avoid having to escape the double quotes. However, with a single quote, I cannot embed the variable within the quote.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
echo "<div id='content'><ul class='pageitem'><li class='store'><a href='index.html'><span class='image' style='background-image: url(" . $zeile['image'] . ")'></span><span class='name'>" . $zeile['title'] . "</span><span class='arrow'></span></a></li></ul></div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use

try this:

```
echo "<div id=\'content\'><ul class=\'pageitem\'><li class=\'store\'><a href=\'index.html\'><span class=\'image\' style=\'background-image: url(".$zeile['image'].")></span><span class=\'name\'>".$zeile['title']."</span><span class=arrow></span></a></li></ul></div>";
```

Check Single quotes also.

And even I agree with "Parkyprg", use html content outside php.

Answer (score 0):

you may replace each " with "+"\""+".
It works in all scripting languages.